# C# compare two Lists and update it's column values

Tags: c#, list, compare

I've got two C# lists (List listA and List listB) 
how can I compare these two and if duplicate (of specific columns ex. ID_num and ID_cust) is found then update column "ID_duplicate" which is value of listB's columns ID.

```
DataSet ds =  subMain;

List<string> listA = (from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                      Select r.Field<string>("ID_num") + 
                       r.Field<string>("ID_cust")).ToList();

DataSet dsMain = Mains;

List<string> listB = (from r in dsMain.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                      select r.Field<string>("ID_num") + 
                      r.Field<string>("ID_cust")).ToList();
```

I want that `listA` will contain new column `ID_duplicate` with value `ID_num` from `listB`.

So that duplicates will be somehow linked with this `ID_num`.

I will then update that `ID_duplicate` to database.

Edit: 
Added more explanation in comment bellow.

Comment: Please show us your code so far. This might help in understanding your question.

Comment: so bascially you have two datatables and you want to find out duplicates of a given column in one datatable in a given column in another datatable?

Comment: In short, 
I've got two datasets which are transformed to two lists (listA,listB). 
Both lists have the same columns (columnA,columnB), but listA has also got column ID_duplicate (null value is default) and listB has column ID
I want to compare listA to listB and if duplicates are found, update column ID_duplicate (in listA) with value from column ID in listB and then update values in DB table, let say listA is table "tableA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand is a join:

```
var listA = new List<Row> { 
    new Row { ID= 1, IdNum = 1, IdCust = 1 }, 
    new Row { ID= 2, IdNum = 1, IdCust = 2 }, 
    new Row { ID= 3, IdNum = 2, IdCust = 1 }, 
    new Row { ID= 4, IdNum = 1, IdCust = 3 }, 
    new Row { ID= 5, IdNum = 3, IdCust = 1 }, 
    new Row { ID= 6, IdNum = 4, IdCust = 1 } 
};

var listB = new List<Row> { 
    new Row { ID= 1, IdNum = 5, IdCust = 1 }, 
    new Row { ID= 5, IdNum = 6, IdCust = 2 }, 
    new Row { ID= 7, IdNum = 2, IdCust = 1 }, 
    new Row { ID= 9, IdNum = 1, IdCust = 3 }, 
    new Row { ID= 11, IdNum = 7, IdCust = 2 }
};

    var t = (from a in listA
             join b in listB on a.IdCust.ToString() + a.IdNum.ToString() 
             equals 
             b.IdCust.ToString() + b.IdNum.ToString()
             select new
             {
                ID = a.ID,
                IdUpdate = b.ID
             }).ToArray();

foreach (var item in t)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID {0} IdUpdate {1}", item.ID, item.IdUpdate);
}
```

Here the Row class

```
class Row
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int IdNum { get; set; }

    public int IdCust { get; set; }
}
```

Obviusly you can create a calculated column on Row class like this

```
public string ValueToCompare
{
   get
   {
      return this.IdNum.ToString() + this.IdCust.ToString();
   }
}
```

and use this on join for comparison

Max

Comment: Max would this work with ListView(so that it can be used to display in listview, not list) ? 
I'm using windows forms. 

Tnx!

Comment: I don't know, in your example you fill List<string> objects with the dataset's value, and based my example on this approach, instead of DataSet try Entity Framework .....